# Another user merged their answer with mine

Tags: discussion, answers, edits

A user [merged their answer with mine](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23640987/revisions), and to be honest they kind of re-iterated exactly what I said.

What should be done in this situation? Is this acceptable?

One of the approaches I figured would be appropriate is to roll-back the changes and ping them in a comment thanking them for the contribution but mentioning that it is unnecessary, but I'm sure if that is preferred.

Comment: It's odd indeed. Ask them what their intention was (sometimes people get distracted, confused or interrupted in their work), if answer is not satisfactory revert edit or assimilate the parts of their edit that improve your answer.  Then, move on to the next question.

Comment: Roll 'er back, it's *your* post after all.  While I'm sure he was just trying to be helpful, that edit was rather clearly outside the scope of what should be edited in.

Comment: I did; what is weird is that he edited it out of *his* answer and put it into *mine*. Not sure exactly what he thought that would fix.

Comment: I ended up rolling back my answer. As [Roippi stated](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254733/another-user-merged-their-answer-with-mine#comment20558_254733), albeit an attempt to be helpful, it wasn't adding anything to my answer and it fell outside of what my answer was addressing.

Comment: Did this 'issue' really need a question on meta?