# What to do with answers taking over yours?

Tags: discussion, edits, duplicate-answers, attribution

Few weeks ago I was going through my old answers and found out one with score 0 and 25K views, where the accepted one had +40.

I gave a solution A and the accepted one gave a solution B, a couple of minutes before. Both quite equivalent, mine having the good thing of avoiding opening a sub-shell, which is kind of a good practise in bash. OP accepted the solution B and I don't blame anybody for it, it is part of the game :)

Few months after the question was made, the accepted answer got some feedback from another user that lead to an extension that is the exact same approach of mine. The answerer commented back with a message like `provided an alternative to address your concern. (fedorqui had already addressed it too.)`.

So now the accepted answer is A+B.

When I noticed, I commented in the answer that it would be good to have some kind of attribution to my answer, but nothing has been replied by the answerer.

So now my [I think as good as the other one] answer lies on the bottom of the page with score 0, whereas the other one gets more and more upvotes using something I already wrote in the first place. What should I do?

I have read the related [Should I downvote on an answer that includes what is essentially the same as mine, after they have answered?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262091/should-i-downvote-on-an-answer-that-includes-what-is-essentially-the-same-as-min) but still I am not certain about what should be done apart from what I already did.

Comment: You win some, you lose some. Move on. Answer more questions. My most flippant answer on SO is also my highest voted - the one I spent most time and effort on is one of the lowest. Ce la vie.

Comment: Moving on to the question, IMO: you always have the option here to be the unsung hero and delete your now obsolete answer. There isn't really any foul play going on, just actions and reactions done after a long passage of time.

Comment: @Gimby I don't think it is fair to have another answer making yours obsolete. It is the whole point about attribution. Otherwise all questions will end up with a unique answer that summarizes the rest of them...

Comment: @fedorqui *Otherwise all questions will end up with a unique answer that summarizes the rest of them* - you say that like it's a *bad* thing!

Comment: @Jamiec to me, it is unless it is a wiki answer. In general, I prefer answers to be different and have the effect of time to determine what is the best approach.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misreading, but if the answerer made a comment to the effect of "fedorqui had already addressed it too" then isn't that attribution?

Comment: Is that particularly bad? I've made edits to my answers that say "as _____ suggested, you can also do B (link to answer)"

Comment: @samgak As I understand it, comments are supposed to be treated as though they may all spontaneously get up and walk away someday, so a comment would not be an appropriate place for attribution given that it could disappear without notice. Attribution should be within the answer itself.

Comment: All answers are wiki answers, or we wouldn't allow people to edit other people's posts.

Comment: This is all a bit ridiculous IMO. Did you invent that "trick" using process substitution and think I didn't know it also? That's a canonical way of doing what wasn't even asked in the question. Have your reference, that's fine, but make sure your link works next time.

Comment: If nothing else, it'll help keep you in practice for dealing with the real world, where this sort of thing happens every day - often with real money or other assets rather than just imaginary Internet points. I realize this is basically "it could be worse," but sometimes that's all there is to say. =\

Comment: *(fedorqui had already addressed it too.)* - *it would be good to have some kind of attribution to my answer*. Seems like the answerer did all he could, no? What do you expect him to reply with? He can't force other people to vote your answer up as well.

Comment: @Don'tPanic The other answerer did mention his post, though. I think fedorqui is referring to the reputation not going to his answer as well, but I'm not sure what he expects them to do about it..

Comment: @Mat I just claim that a proper reference would be kind since you updated your answer many months after with something I mentioned in the very beginning. Full stop.

Comment: I had an answer where months later someone posted a "Thanks!  <copy and paste from my answer> worked for me!".  For a long time it was actually catching up to my answer in upvotes.  I think it eventually got deleted because I can't find it now.  But anyway the moral of the story was that life went on and I survived with no injuries.

Answer (score 37):

This is a knowledge curation site, not a competition. It stings a little when this sort of thing happens, but remember why you're here: to share your knowledge with other programmers world wide. Your answer just got shared more! (And improved upon, by the sound of it.)

Comment: I suspect that the following text from the OP's personal page is rather telling and explains a lot: _"I just added my Amazon wishlist for those **willing** to give me more than an upvote."_ (emphasis mine)

Comment: @enhzflep I'm not clear on what your point is. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I take the sentence I quoted to be indicative of the OPs view regarding votes/reward for answering questions. I often read more into thangs than was ever in them, and may be doing so again, however the use of the word 'willing' as opposed to say, 'that wish' indicates to me that he wants to receive votes/real stuff for his answers here. If this is the case, it would help explain why it is a matter of concern to him if his answers receive little recognition. Personally, I'm only interested in providing something of value that aids someone who asked a question. I expect nothing back.

Comment: @enhzflep That's what I thought you meant, but I wasn't entirely sure. Thanks for clarifying. =)

Comment: @enhzflep I think you are overthinking my old profile message. I am not a native English speaker and I thought "willing" meant "who would like to". I just checked that after your comment and removed it, because it is very far away from my thinking. What you are deducting here based on a single verb is very far away from  the reality: I have been in this community for 2.5 years and contributed with more than 2K answers without expecting anything "solid" from it, apart from some knowledge.

Answer (score 6):

Breathe in. Then breathe out. Feel the responsibility for making the world better. Just remember that when a beginner, stackoverflow maybe used to help you, and maybe posts with zero votes did that too. Just give damn that numbers, your reputation is enough for everything to use. People of the world are grateful for your work and taken time.

Answer (score 2):

So what you're saying is that there's an answer essentially same as yours which was posted before, which was missing one secondary detail? I'm sorry to say it, but why do you expect your answer upvoted, exactly? I know it hurts to throw away your own work, but IMO you should have removed your answer and posted a comment to the accepted answer saying how to avoid running a sub-shell.

Your claims for proper attribution are also dubious in my eyes. Are you the first person on earth to find out how to avoid sub-shells? Are you sure that the update to answer B borrows information from your answer and not from the comment of that other user?

There's also the [fastest gun](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) phenomenon on SO, and you have to take it into account whether you like it or not.

PS. Sorry for being harsh here, I'm not quite good at sugar-coating.